# Blender 3.4.0 Startup Error in Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: installation

I just installed Blender 3.4 on my ancient late-2011 iMac, as 3.4 is supposed to be the latest version that will run on my machine. When I try to run it, I get the following error message,
[image]

My iMac is one of the educational models. I'm wondering if the GPU is the problem?
My machine specs are as follows,
[image]

Comment: This is a Q&A site run by volunteers. No-one here is a Blender developer or has any association with the Blender Foundation and questions about what seems to be a bug are off-topic here. To report a bug go to https://projects.blender.org/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to install and run Blender 3.3.7 just fine. I guess that's as far as I can go on my current Mac?